# Need to match HTML tags and insert another tag around xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have a  xml file (pretty large file) that has different html tags, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<feed xmlns="http://www.ixtens.com/xml/mbapi/R1.4">
```

Sloan Street Classic Tote in Red

```
<Attribute name="SupplierName" domain="CommonTaxonomy">Red</Attribute>
```

**I want to add  tags where there is an attribute. like below:**

```
<Attribute name="SupplierName" domain="CommonTaxonomy"><value>Red</value></Attribute>
```

I tried everything in php, but can't get it right.

Please help me. i was looking as convert every character in string then preg match

But did not helped.

I have to do this for every tags with attributes. moreover  to be changed to

How i did:
(preg_match("/(?![^>]*\bencoding)(?![^>]*\bfeed)<[^>]+['=']/", $line, $matches))
preg_replace("/<(.+?[>^])>/","<$1><value>",$line)

But it is not working

regards,
Maverick

Comment: People saying that regex shouldn't be used to parse html/xml in 3.. 2.. 1..

Comment: You should share your code / attempts.

Comment: I posted my attempts, I have to do the same for all tags with attributes...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
(<Attribute.*?>)(.*?)(<\/Attribute>)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oJ2nU5/1)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Very much for your answer. Is their any Regular expression to find all the tags with an attribute, except starting two lines, so that i can replace the value in all the tags with attribute.

Comment: @user280960 glad to help. Yes you could do something like this http://regex101.com/r/oJ2nU5/2. But you could create a new question to get it answered to avoid having multiple questions at once.

Comment: Thanks Fede, so Full Question is:
1) I have to change (<value) to (<values)
2) I have to change (</value>) to (</values>)
3) I have to add <value> and </value> after the tags with attributes
eg: final will be,

    <values lang="en-us"><value>Sloan Street Classic Tote in Red</value></values>    
    <Attribute name="SupplierName" domain="CommonTaxonomy"><value>Red</value></Attribute>                                                       will appreciate your help

Comment: @user280960 it's difficult to follow your comment, but if you want to get the code go to the link I sent you and click on "Code Generator". It will give you the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
<(Attribute)(\b[^>]*>)([^<>]*)(?=<\/\1)
```

Replacement string:

```
<\1\2<value>\3</value>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/13)

Comment: Could be optimized slightly like: `<(Attribute)(\b[^>]*>)([^<>]*)(?=<\/\1)` to prevent backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with xml content you can use DOMDocument (that is designed for this kind of task):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($data);

$AttributeTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Attribute');

foreach ($AttributeTags as $node) {
    $value = $node->nodeValue;
    $valueTag = $dom->createElement('value', $value);
    $node->replaceChild($valueTag, $node->firstChild);
}

echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML());
```